# Root Test Absolute Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

How would I use the root test to test for convergence / divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac {(n)^{1-3n}} {4^{2n}} $$

I tried setting top and bottom to the power of 1/2n and then 1/1-3n but I ended up with contradictory answers.

Taking $1/2n$ power of both I would get $(n)^{1-3n/2n}$ divided by 4, which tends to 0 as n tends towards infinity, so converges.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: $1-3n \leq -2n$

Comment: @geetha290krm Would raising both sides to the power of (1/1-3n) also give me the correct answer? I would get n / 4^(2n/1-3n), which as n tends to infinity gives infinity / 4^(-2/3) = infinity * 4^(2/3) = infinity = diverges

Comment: Root test says $\sum a_n$ is convergent if $\lim \sup a_n^{1/n}<1$. Why would you raise to power $\frac  1 {1-3n}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm or is it because in the root test you can only raise both sides to the power of 1/kn ?

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comments, your conclusion is right, indeed, as an alternative, we have that

$$\frac {(n)^{1-3n}} {4^{2n}}= \frac {n} {n^{3n}4^{2n}} \implies \left(\frac {(n)^{1-3n}} {4^{2n}}\right)^{\frac1n} = \left( \frac {n} {n^{3n}4^{2n}}\right)^{\frac1n} =\frac {n^{\frac1n}} {n^{3}4^{2}} \to 0$$